# vue-i18n sharedMessages based on component values doesn't seem to be working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-i18n

We have some VueJS components that render content for all resources that we can fetch from the server based on the route parameter.  All resources are represented by their own class (we use [vue-api-query](https://github.com/robsontenorio/vue-api-query) for this).

Basically, any resource we have, is defined as follows:

```js
export default class Invoices extends Model {
    resource() {
        return 'invoices';
    }

    get i18n() {
        return {
            en: {
                resource: 'Invoice | Invoices'
            },
            nl: {
                resource: 'Factuur | Facturen'
            }
        };
    }
}
```

When we have a component that is resource specific, we want to do the following:

```js
<template>
   <div>
      Title could go here: Lis of all {{$tc('resource', 2}}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import models from './models';

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                resource: new models[this.$route.params.resource](); 
            };
        }, 
        i18n: {
            sharedMessages: this.resource.i18n
        }
    }
```

that doesn't seem to be working. 
I also tried pulling in the sharedMessages using a function:

```js
i18n: {
    sharedMessages: () => { return this.resource.i18n; }
}
```

that didn't resolve it either.
It looks as if we are unable to use it this way.
I double checked and printing `{{resource.i18n.en.resource}} correctly prints the string that I expected.

Any thoughts on what I am overseeing, or simply isn't supported and a workaround to get the results that we're looking for?

Just created a [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-21l7z?fontsize=14) for it as well.

thanks again!
David

Comment: Hi David, I don't know if I completely understand, but if you want to change the language, you just need to set: this.$i18n.locale = 'en' right??
Since you are getting the lang from the router, you can set it in some lifecycle method (eg. created).

Comment: Hiya - thanks for replying, but you didn't get the issue.  The issue is that I can not load the sharedMessages from this.resource.i18n in a component.  That is basically what I'm trying to achieve.  Docs on the sharedMessages options are available at https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/component.html#shared-locale-messages-for-components

Answer (score 0):

You missed just single thing here. i18n works before data() in vue component. So this.resource won’t work.

To solve it, you can use it like below:

```
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      resource: new TestClass()
    };
  },
  i18n: {
    messages: {
      en: {
        local: "Local message in English"
      },
      nl: {
        local: "Lokaal bericht in het Nederlands"
      }
    },
    sharedMessages: new TestClass().i18n,
  }
};
```

If you want to go on with data, you can use mergeLocaleMessage.

```
import i18n from '@/i18n.js'; //your plugin path.
i18n.mergeLocaleMessage(i18n.locale, this.resource.i18n[i18n.locale]);
```

Comment: Heya - I know, but that is in fact my main question. TestClass in this example is a class that is passed in via a property.  I tried making the question a little easier by narrowing the question down to what we really need: use a property (through props or from data) in the sharedMessages...

Comment: @DavidHeremans, so in that case you can use mergeLocaleMessage. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: That doesn’t work either as that registers is for the global i18n.  When I have two components on the page (for instance two grids), the second merge is overriding messages for the first merge.  We moved from the mergeLocaleMessage to the sharedMessages in an attempt to resolve this.